# $\mathbb{R}^3$ not diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^3\setminus \{0\}$

Tags: differential-geometry

I have to show, that $\mathbb{R}^3$ is not diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^3\setminus \{0\}$.

That means, I have to show that there are no two smooth maps $f\colon\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3\setminus \{0\}$ and $g\colon \mathbb{R}^3\setminus \{0\} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ such that $f \circ g$ is the identity on $\mathbb{R}^3\setminus \{0\}$.

Does anyone has a tip how to solve this?

Comment: Assume there is a homeomorphism and derive a contradiction maybe?

Comment: Consider the homology group $H_2$

Answer (score 4):

In fact they are not even homotopy equivalent. $\mathbb{R}^3$ is homotopy equivalent to a point, whereas $\mathbb{R}^3 \setminus \{ 0 \}$ is homotopy equivalent to $S^2$. These can be distinguished by e.g. their second homology $H_2$.

For a more differential argument you can try comparing second de Rham cohomology. On $\mathbb{R}^3 \setminus \{ 0 \}$ you can write down a $2$-form which is closed but not exact (because it integrates nontrivially over a sphere $S^2$ around the origin: for some physical inspiration think about [Gauss's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_law)), but on $\mathbb{R}^3$ all closed $2$-forms are exact. This reflects the fact that $H^2_{dR}(\mathbb{R}^3) = 0$ but $H^2_{dR}(\mathbb{R}^3 \setminus \{ 0 \}) \cong \mathbb{R}$.

Beyond that it depends on what tools you're supposed to have access to.

Comment: I suppose I have to use the 2-form $\omega= \frac{1}{x^2+y^2+z^2}(x \:dy\wedge dz - y\: dx \wedge dz + z\: dx\wedge dy)$ but I do not understand what this form represents.

Comment: @monoid: I think it can be interpreted as describing the electric field of a point charge at the origin. I don't know if that's the sort of thing you have in mind.